# For loop returning only first json Object Flutter

Tags: json, listview, flutter, dart

While I tried to fetch data from a JSON am only able to return the first object.
I had mentioned the statement which I think the issue is. I want to return all the available object from the JSON so that I shall display it in a list of cards. I need to return all the JSON objects and pass it to another page containing list of cards. If anyone knows the solution please help me fix it.
Thanks in advance.

```
import 'dart: convert';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:tts/tts.dart';
import 'package:wiizboo/service/Chatmsg_service.dart';
import 'package:wiizboo/widget/a%20copy.dart';
import 'package:wiizboo/widget/chat_in_message.dart';
import 'package:wiizboo/widget/chat_out_message.dart';
import 'package:wiizboo/widget/form.dart';
import 'package:wiizboo/widget/image_camera.dart';
import 'package:wiizboo/widget/image_gallery.dart';

class ChatMessageModel with ChangeNotifier {
  String data;
  List accntdet;

  ChatmessageService chatservice = ChatmessageService();
  List<Widget> messages = <Widget>[];

  ChatMessageModel() {
    sendMsg("Hi");
  }

  Future handlesubmission(String chattext) {
    Widget message = new ChatInMessage(
      text: chattext,
      name: "Me",
      type: true,
    );
    addMsg(message);
    sendMsg(chattext);
  }

  addMsg(Widget msg) {
    messages.insert(0, msg);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  sendMsg(String msg) {
    chatservice.SendMsg(msg).then((String msg) {
      responseBuilder(msg);
    });
  }

  responseBuilder(String msg) {
    Widget message;
    String identifier = '';

    var arr = msg.split("~");
    if (arr.length > 1) {
      identifier = arr[0];
      msg = arr[1];
    } else {
      msg = arr[0];
    }

    switch (identifier) {
      case 'email_phone':
        message = new Forms(onSubmitted: (String val) {
          Widget a = new ChatInMessage(
            text: val,
            name: "Me",
            type: true,
          );
          addMsg(a);
          sendMsg(val);
        });
        break;

      case 'selfie':
        message = new ImageCamera(onSubmitted: (String imageres) {
          Widget b = new ChatInMessage(
            text: imageres,
            name: "Me",
            type: true,
          );
          sendMsg(imageres);
        });
        break;

      case 'aadhar':
        message = new ImageGalery(onSubmitted: (String imageres) {
          Widget b = new ChatInMessage(
            text: imageres,
            name: "Me",
            type: true,
          );
          sendMsg(imageres);
        });
        break;

      case 'account_info':
        print(msg);
        data = msg;
        String receivedJson = data;
        List<dynamic> list = json.decode(receivedJson);
        accntdet = list;
        int l = list.length;
        print(l);

//------------ the statement --------//
        for (dynamic account in accntdet) {
          message = new AccountInfo(
            l: l,
            iban: account['ibn_no'],
            accno: account['account_no'],
            sort: account['sort-code'],
            currency: account['currency'],
          );
        }
//----------//

        print(message);
        break;

      default:
        message = new ChatOutMessage(
          text: msg,
          name: "WzBoo..",
        );
        Tts.speak(msg);
    }

    addMsg(message);
  }
}
```

Comment: You are creating one instance of `AccountInfo` then in `for`loop you're setting the same variable instead of pushing into a list. Also you should bring `print(message)`into `for` bloc

Answer (score 0):

Change this bloc

```
     class ChatMessageModel with ChangeNotifier {
  String data;
  List accntdet;

  ChatmessageService chatservice = ChatmessageService();
  List<Widget> messages = <Widget>[];

  ChatMessageModel() {
    sendMsg("Hi");
  }

  Future handlesubmission(String chattext) {
    Widget message = new ChatInMessage(
      text: chattext,
      name: "Me",
      type: true,
    );
    addMsg(message);
    sendMsg(chattext);
  }

  addMsg(Widget msg) {
    messages.insert(0, msg);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  sendMsg(String msg) {
    chatservice.SendMsg(msg).then((String msg) {
      responseBuilder(msg);
    });
  }

  responseBuilder(String msg) {
    Widget message;
    String identifier = '';

    var arr = msg.split("~");
    if (arr.length > 1) {
      identifier = arr[0];
      msg = arr[1];
    } else {
      msg = arr[0];
    }

    switch (identifier) {
      case 'email_phone':
        message = new Forms(onSubmitted: (String val) {
          Widget a = new ChatInMessage(
            text: val,
            name: "Me",
            type: true,
          );
          addMsg(a);
          sendMsg(val);
        });
        break;

      case 'selfie':
        message = new ImageCamera(onSubmitted: (String imageres) {
          Widget b = new ChatInMessage(
            text: imageres,
            name: "Me",
            type: true,
          );
          sendMsg(imageres);
        });
        addMsg(message);
        break;

      case 'aadhar':
        message = new ImageGalery(onSubmitted: (String imageres) {
          Widget b = new ChatInMessage(
            text: imageres,
            name: "Me",
            type: true,
          );
          sendMsg(imageres);
        });
        break;

      case 'account_info':
        print(msg);
        data = msg;
        String receivedJson = data;
        List<dynamic> list = json.decode(receivedJson);
        accntdet = list;
        int l = list.length;
        print(l);

//------------ the statement --------//
        for (dynamic account in accntdet) {
          message = new AccountInfo(
            l: l,
            iban: account['ibn_no'],
            accno: account['account_no'],
            sort: account['sort-code'],
            currency: account['currency'],
          );
        print(message);
        addMsg(message);
        }
//----------//


        break;

      default:
        message = new ChatOutMessage(
          text: msg,
          name: "WzBoo..",
        );
        Tts.speak(msg);
        addMsg(message);
    }


  }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have elements  in your list. try it out by using a list of static json(by putting items manually like : `var list = [{'itemA1':value, "itemA2":value,...}, {"itemB1": value}]` let me know if it works